# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function - Elementor Function

Tags: plugins

Goal : Fix Elementors ridiculous usage of duplication in their sticky header.

What I have done :

I am adding an additional option space for Sticky Option. This is super basic, not a whole lot of options. Just noticed on a client site who is using elementor which sucks, that the Sticky Header is duplicated... WHY!!!

Here is what I have coded using Elementors strangely well written custom coding section.

I believe I have hit paydirt, still havent added the js to back it but, getting this Uncaught ArgumentCountError.Did not include the plugin description section.

```
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

add_action('elementor/element/section/section_advanced/after_section_end', function ($section) {
    $section->start_controls_section(
        'section_sticky',
        [
            'label' => __('Sticky', 'elementor-sticky-options'),
        ]
    );

    $section->add_control(
        'sticky_enable',
        [
            'label' => __('Enable Sticky', 'elementor-sticky-options'),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SWITCHER,
            'label_on' => __('Yes', 'elementor-sticky-options'),
            'label_off' => __('No', 'elementor-sticky-options'),
            'return_value' => 'yes',
            'default' => 'no',
            'frontend_available' => true,
            'prefix_class' => 'sticky-section-option',
        ]
    );

    $section->add_control(
        'sec_sticky_offset',
        [
            'label' => __('Sticky Offset (px)', 'elementor-sticky-options'),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::NUMBER,
            'default' => 0,
            'condition' => [
                'sticky_enable' => 'yes',
            ],
        ]
    );

    $section->end_controls_section();
});

add_action('elementor/frontend/section/after_render', function ($element, $section) {
    $settings = $section->get_settings();
    if (!empty($settings['sticky_enable']) && $settings['sticky_enable'] === 'yes') {
        $element->add_render_attribute('_wrapper', 'class', 'sticky-section-option');
    }
}, 10, 2);
```